# Add content of form to 2 different tables cakephp

Tags: database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am building a form with Cakephp 2.x and I want to submit some of the data that is received when submitting it to table A and the other data to table B. Does anyone know how to achieve this in cakephp?

Comment: This is not the case for 2.0

Comment: Uh, I clearly did specify that I am using version 2.x? Next time try to read the question instead of commenting right away.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to look at Cakephp's model documentation.  Looking at it now it seems that `saveMany` could help you with that. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should do what you want follow below way:
**1.** Create method `receiveData()` in `FooController`.
**2.** Create view file `receive_data.ctp` in folder `foo`.

```
$this->Foo->create();
$this->Foo->input('....', array(....));
// other input.
$this->Foo->end();
```

**3.** In `FooController\receiveData()`, When submit, you have data array `$myDataArray` like this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#adding-posts
(Notice: It is **`Foo`** controller).

**4.** Before you save data from submitted data, you maybe need manipulation with submitted data array.
**5.**
You must call Model **`Bar`** inside `FooController` by:

```
$uses = array('Bar');
```

You will save to other table by:

```
$this->Bar->save($myDataArray);
```

(Notice: It is **`Bar`** Model).

Answer (score 0):

Do Table A and Table B represent two different Models? 
if yes saveAssociated might help you.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto

If you want to save the same kind of model n times then saveMany is what you want to do.